# Mongoose: can't query array of dates

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a test document like that:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb6b0ed9cad6e97cfc24c2d"),
    "dates" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-11-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve only dates `$gt: 2020-14-01T00:00:00.000Z`. I tried a lot of combinations but none of them worked for me.

This is one of the queries I tried (taken from Mongodb docs):

```
db.getCollection('things').find({_id: ObjectId("5fb6b0ed9cad6e97cfc24c2d"), "dates.date": { $gt: new Date("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")} } )
```

But it return all the document, not the gt... i tried using new Date and new ISODate too, but same effect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, according to [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) dates are in the format `"<YYYY-mm-dd>"`.
Also more formats are allowed, but If you try to use `2020-14-01` as date it will fail (unless you convert string to date with an specific format) because month is 14.

But, answering the question, you need a query like this:

**EDITED**

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fb6b0ed9cad6e97cfc24c2d"),
    
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "dates": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$dates",
        "as": "item",
        "cond": {
          "$gt": [
            "$$item.date",
            ISODate("2020-01-14T00:00:00.000Z")
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

First `$match` by `_id` to get only the document you want. And then using `$project` to create the fields you want to get. You can filter in the array those values whose field `date` is greater than your date using `$filter` and `$gt`

Note that I've used `2020-01-14` to avoid errors.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5mm_PRE2f58).
Also another [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9gbNLlichvw) using `$dateFromString` in this query.

Edit: You can use [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) and specify a format. Check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ce8jEc8jZgn)

Comment: Thank you @J.F, this is one of approach I tried, but it only return me only one match, which is 2020-02-01, next date grater than 2020-01-14, but not all the dates in the DB.

Comment: if you mean deleting $elemMatch, it return an expression error.. I need to search inside an specific document, not the entire database.

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood the question and comment with "delete `$match` stage" was for other question. So sorry. I've updated the answer.